# Array not reseting function and removing items from alternate array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

In this word game i generate 9 letters randomly wait for users input then check if for each letter of the users input "value" they use only the letters generated at the start

for example if the startwordgame() generated the word maximizes
the user can two i's and m's but only one a, x, z, e and s.. Therefore if they input the word "zebra" or "iii" it would check each letter to the array and at the 3rd letter because b is not in the list or i is used to many times. But if i input "Maze" it would work.

**Issue**
The issue i have is that the variable "checklist" in the "checkWordtolist" function does not reset every time i call the function, this.gameletters array changes even though i'm not defining it a new value anywhere i want game.letters to be a constant after i generate it.

checklist is just be a temporary array that can be reset to the original (this.gameletters) everytime the function is called

though when i remove element of checklist it also removes it from this.gameletters
when i remove the elements from array as i go through

Html Elements

```
<input type="text" class="sumbit"  maxlength="9" size="1" value="" />
```

Javascript Elements

```
function startwordgame() {
    this.gameletters = ["m","a","x","i","m","i","z","e","s"]; //Randomly generated list of 9 letters,

 this.checkWordtolist = function(){ 
            var checklist = this.gameletters;
            value = $(".sumbit").val();

            console.log(this.gameletters);
            for (var i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
                console.log(value[i]);
                if (checklist.indexOf(value[i]) == -1) {

                    console.log("Letter not in list or used more than once");

                } else {    

                    checklist.splice(checklist.indexOf(value[i]),1)

                }
            }
            console.log("valid word") // call check dictionary function 
            value = $(".sumbit").val(""); // reset user's input

    }
```

}

Thank you in advanced :) <3

Comment: `var checklist = this.gameletters;` here it assigns reference of gameletters to checklist, so when u remove element , it affect to both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays are reference types in Javascript, so `var checklist = this.gameletters;` only copies a reference to the array to `checklist`, it doesn't copy the array itself.

This has the effect that when you do `checklist.splice()` you're actually modifying the original array.

The simplest most straightforward way to copy the array the way you want to is this:

```
var checklist = this.gameletters.slice();
```

Basically, take a slice of the original array and assign it to `checklist`,  by not providing any range the slice will consist of every item in the original array.

Answer (score 0):

`checklist` is set to the value of `gameletters` every time your function is called. You could simply skip copying the array to `checklist` and work with `gameletters` in your function.

Comment: That wouldn't work because im using checklist to look if the users input has to many of the same value if i work with gameletters i will just have to define it as a constant somewhere else because its used in other places and needs to be static